# Import from txt (MS Access 2013) to SQL Server 2016 slow

Tags: sql-server, performance, ms-access, insert, adodb

I have a `txt` file on my local PC, this has to be check and then line by line uploaded into SQL Server 2016 using a Stored Procedure from MS Access using ADODB. It looks like Access is running always 2 rows fast and then making a short stop.

In MS Access I'm using this function:

```
Public Function ImportData(FileString As String)
Dim WholeLine As String
Dim cc As Variant

Dim sapPurchaseDocument As String
Dim sapPartNumber As String
Dim sapPartName As String
Dim sapDocumentDate As String
Dim sapSupplier As String
Dim sapPlant As String
Dim sapSLoc As String
Dim sapQuantity As Double
Dim sapUOM As String
Dim sapTargetQuantity As Double
Dim sapDeliveryDate As String
Dim sapPrevQuantity As Double
Dim sapReceivedQuantity As Double
Dim sapIssuedQuantity As Double
Dim sapDeliveredQuantity As Double
Dim sapPurchaseRequisition As String
Dim sapPurchaseRequisitionItem As String
Dim sapCreationIndicatior As String
Dim sapNoOfPositions As Double
Dim totalCount As Integer
Dim sapPurchaseDocumentItem As String

Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
Call GetConnection
Set rs.ActiveConnection = myCN

If Right(FileString, 3) = "txt" Then
    totalCount = GetRowCount(FileString)

    Open FileString For Input As #1
    i = 0
    Do While Not EOF(1)
        Line Input #1, WholeLine

        If Left(WholeLine, 3) = "| 4" Then
            'Debug.Print WholeLine
            cc = Split(WholeLine, "|")

            sapPurchaseDocument = Trim(cc(1))
            sapPartNumber = Trim(Replace(cc(2), ".", ""))
            sapPartName = Trim(Replace(cc(3), "'", ""))
            sapDocumentDate = Right(cc(4), 4) & "-" & Mid(cc(4), 4, 2) & "-" & Left(cc(4), 2)
            sapSupplier = cc(5)
            sapPlant = cc(6)
            sapSLoc = cc(7)
            sapQuantity = Replace(cc(8), ",", "")
            sapUOM = Trim(cc(9))
            sapTargetQuantity = Replace(cc(10), ",", "")
            sapDeliveryDate = Right(cc(11), 4) & "-" & Mid(cc(11), 4, 2) & "-" & Left(cc(11), 2)
            sapPrevQuantity = cc(12)
            sapReceivedQuantity = Replace(cc(13), ",", "")
            sapIssuedQuantity = Replace(cc(14), ",", "")
            sapDeliveredQuantity = Replace(cc(15), ",", "")
            sapPurchaseRequisition = Trim(cc(16))
            sapPurchaseRequisitionItem = Trim(cc(17))
            sapCreationIndicatior = cc(18)
            sapNoOfPositions = cc(19)
            sapPurchaseDocumentItem = Trim(cc(20))
            strSQL = "spInsertUpdateSAPME2M '" & sapPurchaseDocument & "', '" & sapPartNumber & "', '" & sapPartName & "', '" & _
                     sapDocumentDate & "', '" & sapSupplier & "', '" & sapPlant & "', '" & sapSLoc & "', " & _
                     sapQuantity & ", '" & sapUOM & "', " & sapTargetQuantity & ", '" & sapDeliveryDate & "', " & _
                     sapPrevQuantity & ", " & sapReceivedQuantity & ", " & sapIssuedQuantity & ", " & _
                     sapDeliveredQuantity & ", '" & sapPurchaseRequisition & "', '" & sapPurchaseRequisitionItem & "', '" & _
                     sapCreationIndicatior & "', '" & sapNoOfPositions & "', '" & sapPurchaseDocumentItem & "'"
            rs.Open (strSQL)
            DoEvents

        End If
    i = i + 1
    Debug.Print i
    Forms!frm_Overview.lblStatus.Caption = "Record " & i & " of " & totalCount & " loaded. Please wait!"
    DoEvents
    'Refresh
    Loop
MsgBox "Import done"
End If

Close #1

End Function
```

And on SQL Server I have a stored procedure which looks like this:

```
USE [MOBILEPRINT]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[spInsertUpdateSAPME2M]    Script Date: 5/25/2020 11:39:31 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CHANGE NO ACTION
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spInsertUpdateSAPME2M] 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
           @sapPurchaseDocument varchar(50),
           @sapPartNumber varchar(50),
           @sapPartName varchar(300),
           @sapDocumentDate date,
           @sapSupplier varchar(50),
           @sapPlant varchar(100),
           @sapSLoc varchar(50),
           @sapQuantity float,
           @sapUOM varchar(50),
           @sapTargetQuantity float,
           @sapDeliveryDate date,
           @sapPrevQuantity float,
           @sapReceivedQuantity float,
           @sapIssuedQuantity float,
           @sapDeliveredQuantity float,
           @sapPurchaseRequisition varchar(50),
           @sapPurchaseRequisitionItem varchar(50),
           @sapCreationIndicatior varchar(50),
           @sapNoOfPositions varchar(50),
           @sapPurchaseDocumentItem varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN TRANSACTION
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @RESULT int
    DECLARE @UPDATE_CHECK int
    DECLARE @UpdateDate datetime = GetDate()

    BEGIN
        SELECT @RESULT = COUNT(sapPurchaseDocument) FROM SAP_ME2M WHERE sapPurchaseDocument = @sapPurchaseDocument AND sapPartNumber = @sapPartNumber
            IF ISNULL(@RESULT,0) = 0
                BEGIN 
                INSERT INTO SAP_ME2M (
                    sapPurchaseDocument, 
                    sapPartNumber, 
                    sapPartName, 
                    sapDocumentDate, 
                    sapSupplier, 
                    sapPlant, 
                    sapSLoc,
                    sapQuantity, 
                    sapUOM, 
                    sapTargetQuantity, 
                    sapDeliveryDate, 
                    sapPrevQuantity, 
                    sapReceivedQuantity, 
                    sapIssuedQuantity,
                    sapDeliveredQuantity, 
                    sapPurchaseRequisition, 
                    sapPurchaseRequisitionItem, 
                    sapCreationIndicatior, 
                    sapNoOfPositions,
                    ChangeDate,
                    sapPurchaseDocumentItem)
                VALUES
                    (@sapPurchaseDocument, @sapPartNumber, @sapPartName, @sapDocumentDate, @sapSupplier, @sapPlant, 
                    @sapSLoc, @sapQuantity, @sapUOM, @sapTargetQuantity, @sapDeliveryDate, @sapPrevQuantity, 
                    @sapReceivedQuantity, @sapIssuedQuantity, @sapDeliveredQuantity, @sapPurchaseRequisition, 
                    @sapPurchaseRequisitionItem, @sapCreationIndicatior, @sapNoOfPositions, @UpdateDate, @sapPurchaseDocumentItem)
                END
            ELSE
                SELECT @UPDATE_CHECK = COUNT(*) FROM SAP_ME2M WHERE 
                                                                       sapPurchaseDocument          = @sapPurchaseDocument          AND
                                                                       sapPartNumber                = @sapPartNumber                AND
                                                                       sapPartName                  = @sapPartName                  AND
                                                                       sapDocumentDate              = @sapDocumentDate              AND
                                                                       sapSupplier                  = @sapSupplier                  AND
                                                                       sapPlant                     = @sapPlant                     AND
                                                                       sapSLoc                      = @sapSLoc                      AND
                                                                       sapQuantity                  = @sapQuantity                  AND
                                                                       sapUOM                       = @sapUOM                       AND
                                                                       sapTargetQuantity            = @sapTargetQuantity            AND
                                                                       sapDeliveryDate              = @sapDeliveryDate              AND
                                                                       sapPrevQuantity              = @sapPrevQuantity              AND
                                                                       sapReceivedQuantity          = @sapReceivedQuantity          AND
                                                                       sapIssuedQuantity            = @sapIssuedQuantity            AND
                                                                       sapDeliveredQuantity         = @sapDeliveredQuantity         AND
                                                                       sapPurchaseRequisition       = @sapPurchaseRequisition       AND
                                                                       sapPurchaseRequisitionItem   = @sapPurchaseRequisitionItem   AND
                                                                       sapCreationIndicatior        = @sapCreationIndicatior        AND
                                                                       sapNoOfPositions             = @sapNoOfPositions             AND
                                                                       sapPurchaseDocumentItem      = @sapPurchaseDocumentItem
                IF @UPDATE_CHECK = 0
                    BEGIN
                    UPDATE SAP_ME2M SET 
                                        sapPartName                 = @sapPartName                  ,
                                        sapDocumentDate             = @sapDocumentDate              ,
                                        sapSupplier                 = @sapSupplier                  ,
                                        sapPlant                    = @sapPlant                     ,
                                        sapSLoc                     = @sapSLoc                      ,
                                        sapQuantity                 = @sapQuantity                  ,
                                        sapUOM                      = @sapUOM                       ,
                                        sapTargetQuantity           = @sapTargetQuantity            ,
                                        sapDeliveryDate             = @sapDeliveryDate              ,
                                        sapPrevQuantity             = @sapPrevQuantity              ,
                                        sapReceivedQuantity         = @sapReceivedQuantity          ,
                                        sapIssuedQuantity           = @sapIssuedQuantity            ,
                                        sapDeliveredQuantity        = @sapDeliveredQuantity         ,
                                        ChangeDate                  = @UpdateDate
                    WHERE               
                                        sapPartNumber               = @sapPartNumber                AND
                                        sapPartName                 = @sapPartName                  AND
                                        sapDocumentDate             = @sapDocumentDate              AND
                                        sapSupplier                 = @sapSupplier                  AND
                                        sapPlant                    = @sapPlant                     AND
                                        sapSLoc                     = @sapSLoc                      AND
                                        sapPurchaseDocumentItem     = @sapPurchaseDocumentItem
                    END
    END
COMMIT TRANSACTION WITH (DELAYED_DURABILITY = ON);
```

I have to upload around 30000 Records which takes more then an hour at the moment.

If you have suggestions, please let me know.

Comment: Don't process inserts by calling a stored procedure 3.000 times, that's bound to be slow. Instead, use a (temp) table and process that on the SQL server side. Use a disconnected recordset with bulk insert for optimal performance. For further improvements, use `MERGE` to both insert  and update, don't do it in separate statements, especially don't use `SELECT COUNT` twice.

Comment: Looks like the Stored Procedure is not the issue, i try to copy all data from my local table onto the SQL Server with the Statement 
`Docmd.TransferDatabase acExport ......`
And this also takes years, anyone a suggestion to transfer a local table from MS Access to SQL Server fast?

Comment: As said, use a disconnected recordset with bulk insert.

Comment: can you add an example? never used a disconnected rs

Comment: Got it! Super Thanks to Erik! Now i do around 200 Records per second compared to 2 records per second before! Thanks

Comment: Ah, actually just wrote you a sample but glad it works out!

Answer (score 0):

For fast data transfer, use a disconnected recordset with batch operations enabled.

```vb
Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
Call GetConnection
Set conn = myCN
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient
rs.Open "Table1", conn, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockBatchOptimistic
'Disconnect
Set rs.ActiveConnection = Nothing
Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To 3000
    rs.AddNew
    rs.Fields(1) = i
Next
'Reconnect
Set rs.ActiveConnection = conn
'Batch insert
rs.UpdateBatch
Debug.Print Now()
```

For me, this executes in 2 seconds, but it highly depends on the location of SQL server.

Then, process further on the data set when uploaded. Processing on a per-record basis is usually going to be slow.

Comment: Any Idea how i can now give all the Values to my Stored Procedure instead of doing the Update through ADODB?

Comment: You can't. Just write it to a temp table, then process that temp table in SQL server, and delete the temp table afterwards. Looking at your code, you can probably do this in a single `MERGE` statement. Theoretically, you could also use a cursor in SQL server to iterate the records and call the stored procedure many times, but that's inefficient and you likely want to process the entire table at once.

Comment: Understood, realized with all your great help, thanks! ME and the users are happy, it takes now around 3 min for 35000 records to upload.